# Rise up the checked radio button when clicked in dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a dropdown menu to change currencies. I have a model that use JQuery but the structure isn't exactly the same.

The problem is that I want the `div` with the checked input to be the first one when I click on it like in this example:

How can I do that ?

```js
$('.maincar__currency').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});

$(".maincar__currency label").click(function() {
  $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).prop('checked', true);
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $('.maincar__currency').removeClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.maincar__currency {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 32px;
  max-height: 32px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: $shadowBox;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.maincar__currency label {
  display: flex;
  width: 80px;
  height: 32px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: $mediumMainGrey;
  cursor: pointer;
  //box-sizing: border-box;
}

.maincar__currency label:hover {
  background-color: $extraLightGrey;
}

.currency {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.currency input {
  display: none;
}

.currency img {
  //object-fit: contain;
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.currency span {
  display: flex;
  //align-items: center;
  color: $mediumMainGrey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.expanded {
  max-height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maincar__currency">
  <label for="euro-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__euro">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/euro.png" alt="Euro sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" value="euro" id="euro-radio-is" class="euro_radio_is" checked="true">
      <span class="default">EUR</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="dollar-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__dollar">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/dollar.png" alt="Dollar sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="dollar-radio-is" class="dollar_radio_is" value="dollar">
      <span>USD</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="gbp-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__pound">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/pound-sterling.png" alt="Pound sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="gbp-radio-is" class="gbp_radio_is" value="gbp">
      <span>GBP</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="chf-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__chf">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/swiss-franc.png" alt="Swiss franc sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="chf-radio-is" class="chf_radio_is" value="chf">
      <span>CHF</span>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/j0be/pen/jWGVvV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just prepend the clicked label to the container and it will move it to the top:

```js
var $container = $('.maincar__currency'); // cache this for better performance as you use it multiple times

$container.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});

$(".maincar__currency label").click(function() {
  $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).prop('checked', true); 
  // just prepend this label to the container and it will move it to the top:
  
  $container.prepend($(this));
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $container.removeClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.maincar__currency {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 32px;
  max-height: 32px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: $shadowBox;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.maincar__currency label {
  display: flex;
  width: 80px;
  height: 32px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: $mediumMainGrey;
  cursor: pointer;
  //box-sizing: border-box;
}

.maincar__currency label:hover {
  background-color: $extraLightGrey;
}

.currency {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.currency input {
  display: none;
}

.currency img {
  //object-fit: contain;
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.currency span {
  display: flex;
  //align-items: center;
  color: $mediumMainGrey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.expanded {
  max-height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maincar__currency">
  <label for="euro-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__euro">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/euro.png" alt="Euro sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" value="euro" id="euro-radio-is" class="euro_radio_is" checked="true">
      <span class="default">EUR</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="dollar-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__dollar">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/dollar.png" alt="Dollar sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="dollar-radio-is" class="dollar_radio_is" value="dollar">
      <span>USD</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="gbp-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__pound">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/pound-sterling.png" alt="Pound sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="gbp-radio-is" class="gbp_radio_is" value="gbp">
      <span>GBP</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="chf-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__chf">
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/swiss-franc.png" alt="Swiss franc sign">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="chf-radio-is" class="chf_radio_is" value="chf">
      <span>CHF</span>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In example from codepen there is

```
input:checked + label {
display:block;
border-top: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
```

which means that whenever input is checked, the label next to it will get absolute position.

So the idea is that your inputs are below the "selected label" in "static positions", you just pick one by code by adding to the container that you want to show the "absolute class".